# Dart: convert Map to List of Objects

Tags: flutter, dart

Did several google searches, nothing helpful came up. Been banging my head against some errors when trying to do something that should be pretty simple. Convert a map such as `{2019-07-26 15:08:42.889861: 150, 2019-07-27 10:26:28.909330: 182}` into a list of objects with the format:

```
class Weight {
  final DateTime date;
  final double weight;
  bool selected = false;

  Weight(this.date, this.weight);
}
```

I've tried things like: `List<Weight> weightData = weights.map((key, value) => Weight(key, value));`

There's no `toList()` method for maps, apparently. So far I'm not loving maps in dart. Nomenclature is confusing between the object type map and the map function. Makes troubleshooting on the internet excruciating.

Comment: `Map`s have useful getters like `keys` and `values` on which you can call `toList` - depending whether you want the keys or values. There's also `entries` that lets you do: `weights.entries.map<SomeVClass>(someFunction).toList()`

Comment: THIS PROBLEM IS REAL :) => Nomenclature is confusing between the object type map and the map function.

Answer (score 160, accepted):

Following on Richard Heap's comment above, I would:

```
List<Weight> weightData =
  mapData.entries.map( (entry) => Weight(entry.key, entry.value)).toList();
```

Don't forget to call `toList`, as Dart's `map` returns a kind of Iterable.

Comment: What happens if Weight got multiple fields?

Comment: @EngineSense Wouldn't it then follow that your entry value would contain an object itself? You could then use entry.object.att1, entry.object.att2, etc. to instantiate your new Weight object with the correct data from your map.

Answer (score 18):

```
List<Weight> weightData = List();

weights.forEach((k,v) => weightData.add(Weight(k,v)));
```

Comment: for any map call entries , it gives you a List of MapEntry: weights.entries.map((e) => Weight(e.key,e.value)).toList()

Comment: Op simply wanted a list of objects

Answer (score 12):

Sometimes the typecast will fail and you can enforce it by doing:

```
List<Weight> weightData =
  weightData.entries.map<Weight>( (entry) => Weight(entry.key, entry.value)).toList();
```

Example from my project where it wasn't working without typecast:

```
List<NetworkOption> networkOptions = response.data['data']['networks']
          .map<NetworkOption>((x) => NetworkOption.fromJson(x))
          .toList();
```

Answer (score 7):

Use the `entries` property on the `map` object

This returns a `List` of type `MapEntry<key,value>`.

```
myMap.entries.map((entry) => "${entry.key} + ${entry.value}").toList();
```

Answer (score 7):

You can also use a `for` collection to achieve the same.

```dart
var list = [for (var e in map.entries) FooClass(e.key, e.value)];
```

Answer (score 5):

### Details

- Flutter 1.26.0-18.0.pre.106

### Solution

> /libs/extensions/map.dart

```
extension ListFromMap<Key, Element> on Map<Key, Element> {
  List<T> toList<T>(
          T Function(MapEntry<Key, Element> entry) getElement) =>
      entries.map(getElement).toList();
}
```

### Usage

```
import 'package:myApp/libs/extensions/map.dart';

final map = {'a': 1, 'b': 2};
print(map.toList((e) => e.value));
print(map.toList((e) => e.key));
```

Answer (score 4):

If you need to convert Map values to a list, the simplest oneline code looks like this:

```
final list = map.values.toList();
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?

Comment: Sorry, but sometimes simple code can say more than its explanation

Comment: @Tyler2P I think `toList()` is pretty self-explanatory

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

```
List<Weight> weightData = (weights as List ?? []).map((key, value) => Weight(key,value)).toList()
```

or you can try:

```
List<Weight> weightData = List.from(weights.map((key, value) => Weight(key, value)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Vidor answer is correct .any way this worked for me

```
      List<String> list = new List();
  userDetails.forEach((k, v) => list.add(userDetails[k].toString()));
```

Answer (score 1):

Object Class

```
class ExampleObject {
  String variable1;
  String variable2;

  ExampleObject({
    required this.variable1,
    required this.variable2,
  });

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    return {
      'variable1': this.variable1,
      'variable2': this.variable2,
    };
  }

  factory ExampleObject.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
    return ExampleObject(
      variable1: map['variable1'] as String,
      variable2: map['variable2'] as String,
    );
  }
}
```

Convert Map to Object List

```
List<ExampleObject> objectList = List<ExampleObject>.from(mapDataList.map((x) => ExampleObject.fromMap(x)));
```

Answer (score 0):

You simply don't need to. the `values` property is an `Iterable<>` of your objects. You can iterate over this or you can convert it to a list. For example,

```
// ignore_for_file: avoid_print

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_test/flutter_test.dart';

void main() {
  testWidgets("convert Map to List of Objects", (tester) async {
    final weight1 = Weight(const ValueKey("1"), DateTime.now(), 1);
    final weight2 = Weight(const ValueKey("2"), DateTime.now(), 2);

    final map = {weight1.key: weight1, weight2.key: weight2};

    //You don't have to convert this to a list
    //But you can if you want to
    final list = map.values.toList();

    list.forEach((w) => print("Key: ${w.key} Weight: ${w.weight} "));
  });
}

class Weight {
  final Key key;
  final DateTime date;
  final double weight;
  bool selected = false;

  Weight(this.key, this.date, this.weight);
}
```